# Declare p-dialog on @NgModule

Tags: angular8

When replicating this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdxyZuysACc

I have the following error on Angular CLI :

"p-dialog is not a known element. Please add it to @NgModule".

I know that @NgModule belongs to an ".module.ts" file. I declared it there, under the metadata 'imports'. But do I also need to add in under the component's metadata tag 'providers' ?

Ty a lot!

Comment: <p-dialog header="Create Time" [modal]="true" [(visible)]="displayEditDialog" [ngSwitch]="dialogPageIndex"></p-dialog>

Comment: [modal] -> Defines if background should be blocked when dialog is displayed.

Comment: [(visible)] is a boolean that Specifies the visibility of the dialog

Comment: When I used dialogs, I had it into the modules: 
    declarations: [YourDialogComponent],
    entryComponents: [YourDialogComponent],

Answer (score 0):

Have you already added in app.module.ts declarations and entryComponents?:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...,
        **YourDialogModule**
    ],
    exports: [...],
    providers: [...],
    ...
    declarations: [**YourDialogComponent**],
    entryComponents: [**YourDialogComponent**],
})
```

Don't forget to restart your web-app completely after the change.

Comment: I did, thank you a lot!

Comment: So it does work?